# Allow dropdown list to be shown over any parent ignoring their overflow: hidden

Tags: css

I'm making a search/autocomplete component for the project, but when I tested it on one of the typical containers it might be used I got an issue that some search results that won't fit to the container height limit would be just hidden behind. It's probably better if I show you, instead of trying to describe:

```css
.main-container{
  overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: #e1dede;
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.content-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
.search-input{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.search-results {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fbfbbf;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: none;
  text-align: start;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.search-item{
  padding: 5px;  
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
  <input type="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Search..">
  <div class="search-results">
    <div class="search-item">Result #1</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #2</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #3</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #4</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #5</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #6</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #7</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #8</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #9</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #10</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #11</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #12</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #13</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #14</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #15</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #16</div>
    <div class="search-item">Result #17</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Or [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7gL3b05/)

Comment: Well, `overflow:hidden` means overflow gets hidden … There is no easy way to fix this. https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ has an approach, but you’d have to check if that is applicable for your situation, and whether it can be converted to a “one solution fits all scenarios” kind of thing.

Comment: The other option would be that you don’t actually insert this into an element that has its overflow hidden, but outside of it (in terms of DOM), and then calculate what the necessary position to have it show in the right place would be using JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe that is actually a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? If not please let me know.

```css
.main-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #e1dede;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.search-input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.search-results {
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: #fbfbbf;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* height: 100%; */
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.search-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* the 32px is the space the .search-input takes */
  height: calc(100% - 32px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <input type="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Search..">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="search-results">
      <div class="search-item">Result #1</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #2</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #3</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #4</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #5</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #6</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #7</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #8</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #9</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #10</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #11</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #12</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #13</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #14</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #15</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #16</div>
      <div class="search-item">Result #17</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, making the dropdown scrollable was going to be my last resort, but it's not gonna work well in my particular scenario.

Comment: it is the best option as I think.